# Sum of product of Levi-Civita epsilons

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**

Evaluate the sum $\sum_k \varepsilon_{i j k} \varepsilon_{l m k}$ (which contains 3 terms) by considering the result for all possible combinations of $i, j, l, m$; that is,

- (a) $i=j$
- (b) $i=l$
- (c) $i=m$
- (d) $j=l$
- (e) $j=m$
- (f) $l=m$
- (g) $i \neq l$ or $m$
- (h) $j \neq l$ or $m$

Show that
$$
\sum_k \varepsilon_{i j k} \varepsilon_{l m k}=\delta_{i l} \delta_{j m}-\delta_{i m} \delta_{j l}
$$

Source: Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems, 5th ed., Thornton & Marion, pg. 45, question 1-22.

Note: this is in the context of a 3-dimensional problem, so we only need to consider that any of the variables equal $1$, $2$, or $3$.

**Attempt**

We can show that the two sides of the equation are equal by showing that they have the same behaviour for each out the combinations listed in the question.

For the left side, the sum is equal to:

- (a) = (f) = (g) = (h) = $0$.
- (b) = $\delta_{jm}$
- (c) = $-\delta_{jl}$
- (d) = $-\delta_{im}$
- (e) = $\delta_{il}$

It is the right side of the equation where I am running into an issue.  Using (b) as an example, the expression immediately reduces to $\delta_{j m}-\delta_{i m} \delta_{j i}$.  If $i \neq j$ and $i \neq m$, the expression further reduces to $\delta_{jm}$, which is the answer I expect.  However, if $i = j = m$, the expression becomes $0$.

I'm not sure how to justify this extra qualifier of "$i \neq j$ and $i \neq m$" in the context of the left side of the equation to show that the two are equal.